# エラー"list index out of range"の解消方法を探しています。

Tags: python, aws-lambda

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: 例えば `sorted_data` が空リスト `[]` である場合、`sorted_data[-1]` は `list index out of range` になります。

Comment: [編集履歴](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/80603/revisions)をみると何らかの理由で質問者様が質問を消してしまったようです。もし質問に対して、不都合なことがあるのならば[質問を取り消したいですが削除しても良いですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)を確認してモデレータに対応を依頼してください。履歴は残ってしまいます。

Comment: keitaro_so。 問題を修正中です。どうすればいいですか？